# Send email with swift mailer using exchange authentication

Tags: php, smtp, exchange-server, swiftmailer

I am trying to send an email with swift mailer using Exchange authentication. However, I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work.

```
<?php
require_once( "./application/helpers/swift/swift_required.php" );
$transport =
Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance( "31.149.66.10", 25 )
    ->setUsername( "username" )
    ->setPassword( 'password' )
    ->setEncryption( "tls" );
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance( $transport );
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance( "onderwerp" )
->setFrom( array( "from@address.com" ) )
->setTo( array( "to@address.com" ) )
->setBody( "Body van het bericht" );
var_dump( $mailer->send( $message ) );
?>
```

This gives me the error: `Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "nieuwsbrief" using 0 possible authenticators'.`

The server is configured to use TLS and basic authentication (Offer Basic authentication only after starting TLS).

I saw that some people use port 587 for TLS encryption, but I can't connect on port 587. That gives the error: `Connection could not be established with host 31.149.66.10 [No route to host #113].`

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If an Exception of type Swift_TransportException will be thrown it means the authentication fails.

to know early whether or not authentication has failed and an Exception is going to be thrown, call the `start()` method on the created Transport

The following checklist will help you find the problem with this kind of error:

- Check if connection works on other mail clients / platforms, using same port and credentials and encryption
- Check if your php install does not have TLS support enabled.
  You can check if "tls" and/or "ssl" are present in your PHP installation by using the PHP `function stream_get_transports()`

For example you can add it by adding this in php.ini

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

- Make sure there aren't any firewalls blocking connections, 587 might be blocked